# Retrieving nested column in python spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Part of my df schema:

```
-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- error: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hop: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- resuLt: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Rtt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Ttl: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dstoptsize: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dup: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- edst: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- err: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- error: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- flags: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- from: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- hdropts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- mss: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- icmpext: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- obj: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- class: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- mpls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- exp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- label: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- s: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- rfc4884: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- itos: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ittl: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- late: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- mtu: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- rtt: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sIze: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tos: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ttl: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I query nested column, like `result.result.dstopsize` for example? I would like to be able to display everything from `result` or even `result.result` or `result.resuLt` (case-sensitive is on in my spark config)

When I try:

`file_df.select("result.resuLt.dstopsize").show(10)`

I get this error:

`` cannot resolve '`result`.`resuLt`['dstopsize']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''dstopsize'' is of string type.;; ``

EDIT: here is some sample data

````
|_corrupt_record| af|       dst_addr|       dst_name|   endtime|         from|  fw|group_id|lts|  msm_id|  msm_name|paris_id|prb_id|proto|              result|size|     src_addr| timestamp| ttr|      type|
+---------------+---+---------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----+--------+---+--------+----------+--------+------+-----+--------------------+----+-------------+----------+----+----------+
|           null|  4|213.133.109.134|213.133.109.134|1551658584|78.197.253.14|4940|    null| 71|    5019|Traceroute|       3| 13230|  UDP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  40|192.168.0.130|1551658577|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|   37.143.33.15|   37.143.33.15|1551658584|78.197.253.14|4940|15254159| 71|15254159|Traceroute|      12| 13230| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48|192.168.0.130|1551658583|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|  139.162.27.28|  139.162.27.28|1551658612|78.197.253.14|4940|    null| 20|    5027|Traceroute|       3| 13230|  UDP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  40|192.168.0.130|1551658606|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|    45.33.72.12|    45.33.72.12|1551658610|78.197.253.14|4940|    null| 18|    5029|Traceroute|       3| 13230|  UDP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  40|192.168.0.130|1551658608|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|104.237.152.132|104.237.152.132|1551658615|78.197.253.14|4940|    null| 23|    5028|Traceroute|       3| 13230|  UDP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  40|192.168.0.130|1551658608|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|  94.126.208.18|  94.126.208.18|1551658516|37.14.215.183|4940| 9183324| 20| 9183324|Traceroute|      15| 11958| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48| 192.168.22.2|1551658439|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|196.192.112.244|196.192.112.244|1551658554|37.14.215.183|4940| 9181461| 25| 9181461|Traceroute|      15| 11958| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48| 192.168.22.2|1551658474|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|    46.234.34.8|    46.234.34.8|1551658539|37.14.215.183|4940| 9180758| 10| 9180758|Traceroute|      15| 11958| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48| 192.168.22.2|1551658479|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|    185.2.64.76|    185.2.64.76|1551658560|37.14.215.183|4940| 9181290| 31| 9181290|Traceroute|      15| 11958| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48| 192.168.22.2|1551658511|null|traceroute|
|           null|  4|  208.80.155.69|  208.80.155.69|1551658597|37.14.215.183|4940| 9183716|  8| 9183716|Traceroute|      15| 11958| ICMP|[[, 1,, [[,,,,,,,...|  48| 192.168.22.2|1551658546|null|traceroute|
+---------------+---+---------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----+--------+---+--------+----------+--------+------+-----+--------------------+----+-------------+----------+----+----------+```
````

Comment: Put in some reproducible sample data. That will help alot.

Comment: There seems to be some typos in the example.. leaving us with guess work at best.  For instance, you show code to query with dstopsize and resuLt but the schema should match into result and dstoptsize.

Comment: I've only posted the schema for the `result` column, as the other ones I can query without a problem

Comment: It would be very interesting for us, and probably for you too, to design a minimal instance of your problem. Quite often, this process allows to locate the source of the problem more precisely and sometimes even to solve it. Then, if you still need help at this point, please provide us with a way to reproduce your problem (sample data + the minimal code that reproduces the problem). I insist on minimal because it will help us find an answer more easily, and help others with a similar issue in the future find an answer without having to ask.

Comment: My minimal version:  case class C(dstoptsize: Long)
case class B(result: Array[C])
case class A(result: Array[B])
val df = List(A(Array(B(Array(C(10)))))).toDF

df.select("result.result.dstoptsize").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`result`.`result`['dstoptsize']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''dstoptsize'' is of string type.;;

Comment: I suspect the solution will need an UDF.

Answer (score 2):

The `result` is of `array` type so you will need to `explode` or `explode_outer` and then access whatever you need to access.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer, col
file_df.withColumn("exploded_result", explode_outer(col("result")))
       .select("exploded_result.resuLt.dstopsize").show(10)
```

Be cautious though, you will have multiple rows corresponding to individual row depending on number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is atrociously ugly but that would return the correct answer given that you know which column indexes are your nested fields.  That can be computed based on the schema.

```
case class C(x: String, dstoptsize: Long, y: String)
case class B(result: Array[C])
case class A(result: Array[B])

val df = List(
    A(Array(
      B(Array(C("x10", 10, "y10"), C("x11", 11, "y11"))),
      B(Array(C("x12", 12, "y12"), C("x13", 13, "y13")))
      )), 
    A(Array(B(Array(C("x20", 20, "y20"), C("x21", 21, "y21")))))).toDF


val selectInner = udf((x: Seq[Row]) => { x.map(_.getSeq[Row](0).map(_.getLong(1))) })

df.select(selectInner($"result")).show

+--------------------+
|         UDF(result)|
+--------------------+
|[[10, 11], [12, 13]]|
|          [[20, 21]]|
+--------------------+
```